# Excel- Change Cell string Value based on changeable column in another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a dynamic way to change a Cell value " for example : Sheet2!A2 "
whenever a cell column in Sheet1 has changed

For example:
Sheet2!A2= is the cell I want to paste the value

Sheet!B:B= is the column that I insert a string on it.

Whenever I add a value in B:B, this value automatically paste on Sheet2!A2. And when I add another value in B:B or update any cell in B:B, the newest added value automatically pasted on Sheet2!A2. and so on.

Please help me, I think I need to use a VB code or something.

Best

Answer (score 3):

You can enter the following formula in the cell Sheet2!A2, you will get what you wanted.

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("Sheet1!$B",CELL("address"),1),0)=0,"",CELL("contents"))
```

While pasting this formula if you get any warning or error message, Just press enter or click on Ok.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you @Karpak, after I test the function it appears that it take for the first value the value of cell B1 in Sheet1, and after that it take any value in any columns in sheet1 and paste it insheet2!A2.. any idea? the problem that I need to take the changable values in Cell B:B only.

Comment: This formula just takes the last update. But it won't take any other column's value. But it should empty the Sheet2!A2 cell, if you make any change in any sheet. it is not only in any column in Sheet1, even if you change any column in Sheet2 also it empties the Sheet2!A2. At the same time, it paste the value if you may any change in Sheet1!B column.

Comment: =IF(IFERROR(FIND(MENADB!C:C,CELL("address"),1),0)=0,"",CELL(""contents"))

Comment: this is the formula I used based on yours, it did not work as well, any errors I have made?.

Comment: !$ seem to be missing along with the double quotes in "MENADBIC". just put =cell("address") in one cell, based on the value that you see in that, you need to replace the MENADBIC

Comment: MENADB is the name of sheet, and C is the column I wanna copy the updated values in it on my Cell. I have tried to write it this way but only blanks shows to me : IF(IFERROR(FIND("MENADB!$C",CELL("address"),1),0)=0,"",CELL("contents"))

Comment: You need to enter =cell("address") in your MENADB sheet and check what value you are getting when you change any other cell in that sheet. Then use that string in FIND function. it should work. and I am not sure, when the right answer tagging is removed now, when you got what you want